# using \def for my own \newenvironment

Tags: macros, environments

I am trying to write a command that shortens for a command for writing proof. At the moment, I used to use

```
\newenvironment{proof}%
{\textbf{Proof:}}%
{\begin{flushright} $\blacksquare$ \end{flushright}}
```

Now I've gotten tired of writing `\begin{proof}` all the time, so I want to switch to `\pf{ ...content... }` or `\pf[ ...content... ]`.

I tried doing

```
\def\pf[#2\]{\begin{proof} #2 \end{proof}}
```

It didn't like that. I should mention I already have

```
\def\[#1\]{\begin{align}#1\end{align}}
```

for `align`, that's why I didn't use that for `proof`.

Comment: My advice is - not shorten like this. Full form is more semantic.

Comment: Please post a complete, compilable example. That is much more useful than a mere code fragment. It is not a good idea to use `\def` in LaTeX as you are doing. It is just too easy to inadvertently overwrite existing definitions. `\newcommand` does checks. `\def` does not. Generally, you should use the TeX commands only when it is really necessary and you know why it is necessary. Always use the LaTeX versions if you can. If you want more flexibility, see `xparse`.

Comment: My complete example is literally just \documentclass, \begin{document} everything in the post \end{document}.

Comment: If you insist, `\def\pf#1{\textbf{Proof:}\ #1\begin{flushright} $\blacksquare$ \end{flushright}}`.  The usage would be `\pf{blah blah}`.

Comment: No! Don't do it like that! A bracket in the text of the proof would stop absorbing the argument leaving you with puzzling error messages.

Comment: Why define your own when `amsthm` defines a perfectly good env. Wouldn't you in this case risk that a page break is inserted before the end marker.

Comment: apart from the question about the syntax, I'd agree with the other commenters that you would be better to define proof using ntheorem or amsthm or theorem packages, there is no control over white space or page breaking in the form you have here.

Answer (score 5):

I very strongly recommend ***not*** doing this. However, it is probably not as bad as what you've done for `align` so, if you must:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,amssymb}
\NewDocumentCommand \pf { +r[] } {%
  \noindent\textbf{Proof:}
    #1\hspace*{\fill}\nolinebreak$\blacksquare$}

\begin{document}

 \pf[
   Alice saw Nobody on the road, whereas the King did not.\\
   So, Alice has sharper eyes than the King and Nobody is travelling on the road.]
 \pf[
   Alice saw Nobody on the road, whereas the King did not.\\
   Hence, Alice has sharper eyes than the King.]

\end{document}
```

[image: shorthand proof]

**EDIT:** Deal slightly better with line/page breaks. [But, as I said above, this is really not a good way to do this. There are packages and environments designed to get this stuff right while also keeping your code intelligible!]

Comment: and the `\blacksquare` merrily goes onto a new page by itself if the proof is at the bottom of a page.

Comment: @barbarabeeton This version may do slightly better but basically, I think that doing things this way is nuts. There are already much, much better ways to do this kind of thing...

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't advice this, but this works (without any warranty)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\newenvironment{proof}%
{\textbf{Proof:}}%
{\hfill$\blacksquare$}
\def\pf#1{\begin{proof} #1 \end{proof}}
\begin{document}
  \pf{some proof here}
\end{document}
```

[image]

It is better

1. to use amsthm and its environments for `proof` etc.
2. to use `\newcommand` instead of `\def` as former is LaTeX way of defining new macros that checks the existence of the macro.

Comment: `ntheorem` is better than `amsthm` for automatic placement of end-of-proof symbol.

Comment: @Bernard I don't think so. I tried `ntheorem` and abandoned it several years ago.

Comment: @egreg, why? We use it all the time with good results.

Comment: @egreg: I didn't say `ntheorem` is *intrinsically*  better. It's a fact that if a proof environmment ends in a displayed (group of) equation(s), you don't have to add `\qedhere`. Also, it's easier to customise, in my opinion – perhaps due to a better documentation.

Comment: @Bernard It often fails; search for `ntheorem` on the site and you'll find a case.

Comment: @egreg: Yes, I've heard of bugs, ands I'll search, but Inever had a problem in more than 15 years, except for a very special formatting I wanted for proofs (indented wrt the left margin, while the label had to be wrapped like a lettrine – I finally managed to do it).

Comment: the definition here will put the `\blacksquare` at the beginning of the next line if you are unlucky enough to have proof text that ends near the end of a line, without enough space to accommodate the square.  problem covered in appendix d of the texbook (dirty tricks).